# Add icon in bottom right of InboxStyle notification

Tags: android, notifications

[image: Example notification]

I'm trying to add an icon as indicated by number 5 in the image above. I'm using the InboxStyle class and the NotificationCompat.Builder to build it. I've already called setSmallIcon without luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this is simply a design change in the new version of Android.

Prior to Android 5.0 Lollipop, setLargeIcon sets the large icon on the left and setSmallIcon sets the small icon on the far right side, as you'd expect.

Starting in Android 5.0, setSmallIcon overlays a small icon on the bottom right corner of the large icon. As far as I can tell, there is no way to make the small icon appear on the far right in Lollipop. Please correct me if I'm wrong.